# What GPIO pins are required to Power RPi?

Tags: gpio, usb, power, led

We are using Raspberry Pi Model B:
We used USB connector from PC - confirmed output  - 5V, with 2 leads:
Connected +5V to Pin 2
Connected GND to Pin 6
on connector - [image: GPIO Connector RPi]

Inserted Ethernet cable connected to the HUB/Router. We see the following LEDs:
PWR - Solid RED
ACT - Slow Blink GREEN
TDX, LNK, 100 - **OFF**

Question: Do we need to power other GPIO pins as well example 3v3 or the other 5V (pin 4) to power the PRi? Or what are the pins we need to power to power the RPi?

Thanks.

Comment: please remember that by powering through the GPIO you are over passing the fuses that the pi uses for safety reasons. When you do so you have to be sure that your power supply will work as a charm always :)

Comment: We will consider safety once this issue is resolved...Our tests have shown us that Raspberry PI cannot be powered from the GPIO pins. Has anybody successfully done this?

Comment: @javirs The polyfuse is not there to protect the RPi. It's there to prevent your power supply from catching fire in case the RPi fails.

Answer (score 3):

Powering (with 5V) via one 5V pin and one ground pin is sufficient.  You can use more but it's not needed.

Comment: `You can use more but its not needed` ? Use more what? 3.3v,2.5v and 1.8v comes from 5v.

Comment: I was referring to more than one 5V pin or more than one ground pin.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more please. I still dont understand. You mean conenct 5v to the USB port, the GPIO and also Testpoint at the same time?

Comment: The question is about powering the Pi.  Normally you power the Pi via the microUSB socket.  Alternatively you can power the Pi by supplying 5V to P1-2 and ground to P1-6.  The OP shows a diagram of P1.

Comment: I have read many posts  mentioned here and elsewhere including youtube videos claiming powering from GPIO, but what is answered in the posts does not seem to hold in practice hence a re-post.  Has anybody tried powering RPi from GPIO?

Comment: I've been powering a Pi via P1-2 (5V) and P1-6 (GND) for about 2 years.  The power source is a 5V 4A UBEC running from a 12V laptop power adapter.  I don't understand why you don't just try if you don't believe what you are told.